# Laravel installation error " PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found ... "

Tags: php, laravel

I get below error when trying to install Laravel via composer , what might be the problem ?

OS : Ubuntu

php : 5.6

apache: 2.4

**Error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in /var/www/html/hak/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php on line 21

 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

Comment: What is your installation method?

Comment: composer : `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel `

Comment: composer require psr/log

Comment: Just did a new install everything looks good